# What is the semantic of square brackets after the set denoting coefficients of polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, notation

I have the following excerpt:

Unless stated otherwise, we assume all polynomials take integer coefficients, i.e. a polynomial $f \in  \mathbb{Z}[{\bf y}, x]$ is of the form
$$f(y, x) = a_m · x^{d_m} + a_{m−1} · x^{d_{m−1}} + · · · + a_1 · x^{d_1} + a_0 ,$$
where $0 < d_1 < · · · < d_m$ , and the coefficients $a_i$ are in $  \mathbb{Z}[{\bf y}] $ with $a_m \ne 0$.

What exactly is this $\mathbb{Z}[{\bf y}]$? What is y (and why is it bold)?

I would assume (based on text) that it means that they are integers, but then this notations doesn't make any sense to me (I've seen this before as a notation for polynomials over integers).

Comment: i would interpret the bold $y$ to represent a "vector" of variables $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$.

Comment: Does this then mean $f(y,x)$ is a vector of polynomials not just a single one?

Comment: This is a single polynomial of $n+1$ variables, the variable $x$ is singled out, but those other coefficients $a_i$ are polynomials in the remaining variables $y_1,\dots,y_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further context, I think this is the correct interpretation:

This is another way of viewing a multivariate polynomial. We can view $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ as polynomials in $x$ and $y$, or we can view them as $(\mathbb{Z}[x])[y]$ — if you follow the formalism through, these are equivalent. In the first, we're looking at expressions like

$$ p = a_{00} + a_{10}x^1 y^0 + a_{01}x^0 y^1 + a_{11}x^1 y^1 + \cdots$$

and in the latter, expressions like

$$ p = q_0 + q_1 x + q_2 x^2 + \cdots $$

where the $q_i$ are themselves polynomials in $y$. It's essentially just rearranging the sum (which is finite, despite appearances). This is more convenient for various things.

I've discussed this just for the case of two variables, but we can repeat this with as many as we like: hence we could write $\mathbf{y}$ for $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ (note that this certainly is typographically more compressed), and then the $q_i$ are polynomials in the various $y$s.

Dropping the $x$, I think I may have seen this notation as an instance of [multi-index notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation).